# What can we say about the mean and variance of $X_n$ if $X_n\rightarrow N(\mu,\sigma^2)$?

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, central-limit-theorem

Suppose that, under the conditions of CLT, $X_n\rightarrow N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ in distribution, what can we say about mean and variance of $X_n$?

- $\mathbb{E}\left[X_n\right]\rightarrow\mu$? Or maybe$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\mathbb{E}\left[X_n\right]\rightarrow\mu$ **in distribution**?
- $Var\left[ X_n\right]\rightarrow \sigma^2$?    Or $Var\left[ X_n\right]\rightarrow \sigma^2$ **in distribution**?

Comment: Does there exist something  as $E[X_n] \to L$ in distribution? Only random variables converge to random variables in distribution, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Here is a counterexample.  Let $Z\sim N(0,1)$ and let $X_n=Z$ with probability $1-1/n$ and equal to $Z+n!$ with probability $1/n$.  Then $X_n$ converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$ but the moments of $X_n$ do not behave nicely at all.

As @Shashi pointed out, the convergence *in distribution* of $EX_n$ is a mistake.  $E X_n$ is not a random variable, so the best interpretation of "$EX_n$ converges in distribution" is that the sequence of numbers $EX_n$ converges.  Which, as we have seen, does not necessarily happen.